# Could I change the certificate and provisioning profile for production to allow APNS without upload my binary?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have an error with the certificate and provisioning profile for allowing push notifications, so now, I would like to re-stat the work with the certificate and provisioning profile, after finish, should I upload a new version of the binary????

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upload new version of the binary, just remember `Budle identifier` is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you only changed your certificate,  you wouldn't need to upload a new binary of your app. Only your server would be affected.

But changing the provisioning profile requires uploading a new binary of your app.

Comment: ok thank you, can you tell me please if I have two provisioning profile has the same identifier, does it make a conflict between them?

Comment: @Fatima What do you mean by `same identifier`? Do you mean that they have the same name, or that they refer to the same App ID?

Comment: check screenshot above